# Writing Webservice clients using HttpURLConnection

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I have a question related to Axis2 Webservices .
I have  My Webservice deployed in Tomcat Server .

Right now i am writing a Client for my Webservice using

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        samples.quickstart.StockQuoteServiceStub stub = new samples.quickstart.StockQuoteServiceStub();
        samples.quickstart.StockQuoteServiceStub.GetPrice request = new samples.quickstart.StockQuoteServiceStub.GetPrice();
        request.setSymbol("ABCDE");
        samples.quickstart.StockQuoteServiceStub.GetPriceResponse response = stub
        .getPrice(request);
    }
    catch (org.apache.axis2.AxisFault e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.rmi.RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This works fine.

I have seen from net some clients are written using HttpURLConnection.

Please tell me what is the difference between writing clients by using the former way and the later way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have done give you a more abstract way. It has generated the code for you and you need only to provide the parameters to pass. Here Axis2 users the commons httpclient as to send message using http transport. As you can see Axis2 handles all the transport specific things for you.

On the other hand you can create the soap message to send from your own and send using an httpClient. But there you need to do a lot of work.